# `mysql-server` won't install

Tags: server, 15.10, mysql

I've been trying to install `mysql-server` for 2 hours. The system is on Ubuntu Wily.

There's nothing added in the log files.

```
root@Erman:~# dpkg --configure mysql-server-5.6
Setting up mysql-server-5.6 (5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) ...
2016-02-13 18:15:50 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-02-13 18:15:50 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1) starting as process 25352 ...
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.28 started; log sequence number 1626183
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] Binlog end
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2016-02-13 18:15:50 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2016-02-13 18:15:52 25352 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1626193
insserv: warning: script 'K01vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.6 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.6
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.6`

Comment: @Raphael nope, getting the same error :(

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-server^

Comment: Please refrain from swearing when posting on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've switched from upstart to systemd, and now I can install it without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it's missing two scripts regarding Virtual Network Computing Server (`vncserver`) that's supposed to be from the Linux Standard Base (`LSB`).
Try doing some cleaning, spcifically:

```
sudo sh -c "apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade; apt-get -f install"
```

,and then trying to install again.

I got the idea from: http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=379, but I don't feel as free to recommend deleting things on an assumption.